# Telerik Test Studio for automation testing Windows Phone application

Tags: windows-phone-8, telerik-test-studio

Some my friends suggested me use Telerik Test Studio for automation testing on Windows Phone application.
But I read many time at documentation page of Telerik Test Studio on http://www.telerik.com/teststudio as well as videos on Youtube but I coudn't find any realted documents for Automation Testing for Windows Phone application. 
So I would like to ask whether this tool used for automation testing WP apps. I have to use this tool because of requirement of my project.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't look very hard.

"Craft automated tests for any iOS / Android / Windows Phone 8 native, web and hybrid app. Test across multiple browsers. " (http://www.telerik.com/mobile-testing)

And anyway, if you have to use it, then you must have it, and so you should be asking Telerik